# How to read the valgrind return value from child processes?

Tags: linux, bash, valgrind

i am running valgrind in a bash script to use it for automated testing. I already added the option to return an exit code on error and to trace children.

```
/usr/bin/valgrind --error-exitcode=1 --trace-children=yes ./test_prog
```

My programm forks other processes and I can see the output of valgrind running the different processes in the terminal. The problem is, that the exit code option only seems to work when there is an error in the parent process. Because even though there is an error (SIGSEGV) in one of the child processes the exit code of valgrind is still 0, which means it is useless for the automated testing of several processes.

So is there any option, that would make the parent valgrind catch the error in the child and return it? I already looked into the man page. Maybe there would be another solution to this problem, like grepping the output of the children to the terminal for any error messages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

it's important to implement a proper error handling in the code. Compare following two pieces of code.

A:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

int incr=0;
int loop=1;

void runTicks(const char *n) {
    time_t t;
    char buf[BUFSIZE+1];
    pid_t pid;
    int counter;
    pid=getpid();
    counter=0;
    while(loop) {
        sleep(1);
        t=time(NULL);
        strftime(buf,BUFSIZE,"%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S",localtime(&t));
        printf("%s[%d] %s\n",n,pid,buf);
        counter+=incr;
        if(counter>5) memcpy((void *)1,buf,1); /* this line is for causing SEGV */
    }
}

void handler(int s) {
    if(s==SIGCHLD) {
        printf("Received SIGCHLD\n");
        loop=0;
    }
}

void setHandler() {
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler=handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags=SA_NOCLDSTOP;
    if(sigaction(SIGCHLD,&sa,NULL)!=0) {
        printf("Cannot set signal handler, there is no purpose in running the test\n");
        exit(0);
    }

}

int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    printf("start\n");
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==-1) {
        printf("fork failed\n");
        exit(10);
    }
    if(pid==0) {
        printf("child\n");
        incr=1;
        usleep(500000);
        runTicks("C");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("parent spawned child pid=%d\n",pid);
        setHandler();
        runTicks("P");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

B:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

int incr=0;
int loop=1;

void runTicks(const char *n) {
    time_t t;
    char buf[BUFSIZE+1];
    pid_t pid;
    int counter;
    pid=getpid();
    counter=0;
    while(loop) {
        sleep(1);
        t=time(NULL);
        strftime(buf,BUFSIZE,"%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S",localtime(&t));
        printf("%s[%d] %s\n",n,pid,buf);
        counter+=incr;
        if(counter>5) memcpy((void *)1,buf,1); /* this line is for causing SEGV */
    }
}

void handler(int s) {
    if(s==SIGCHLD) {
        int status;
        printf("Received SIGCHLD\n");
        wait(&status);
        printf("Exit code from child: %d\n",status);
        if(status!=0) exit(status);
        loop=0;
    }
}

void setHandler() {
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler=handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags=SA_NOCLDSTOP;
    if(sigaction(SIGCHLD,&sa,NULL)!=0) {
        printf("Cannot set signal handler, there is no purpose in running the test\n");
        exit(0);
    }

}

int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    printf("start\n");
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==-1) {
        printf("fork failed\n");
        exit(10);
    }
    if(pid==0) {
        printf("child\n");
        incr=1;
        usleep(500000);
        runTicks("C");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("parent spawned child pid=%d\n",pid);
        setHandler();
        runTicks("P");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Run those first without valgrind and compare the exit code of both programs. Then run them under valgrind and enjoy.

Using such construction you even don't need to run it under valgrind, to catch segfaults from child processes.